# Tfa.layers.ESN Example

Tags: python, tensorflow

Does anyone have a working example implementing Each State Network with  `Tfa.layers.ESN.`

Currently, I have the following model

```
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
_________________________________________________________________
digits (InputLayer)          [(None, 41, 4)]           0         
_________________________________________________________________
ESN                          (None, 41, 242)           30492     
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 9922)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
predictions (Dense)          (None, 2)                 19846  
_________________________________________________________________   
Total params: 50,338
Trainable params: 19,846
Non-trainable params: 30,492
_________________________________________________________________
```

The problem that I am having is that once I increase the number of hidden units the accuracy of the model drops instead of increasing, both in training and testing dataset. Also, the accuracy that I got is very low.

Comment: I was wodering the same... did you managed to make it work? I need to make a forecast model using ESN.